# Grouping in tree grid extjs 4.2.1

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

Has anyone implemented grouping in tree grid in extjs 4.2.1, as there is no groupField property in TreeStore ?

Comment: Why you want to group tree grid while nodes are already grouped by their parents?

Comment: @HesamFaridmehr, I want to divide the grid into different sections based on the groupField, is there any cleaner way to do this grouping ?

Comment: You have to nest the tree in such a way that the grouping is part of your tree structure.